# White space is added at bottom when I put Webview inside scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have an Webview which looks like Expandable Listview in android. It is working well when I just loads this in a WebView.

But when I keep this in ScrollView,it adds white Space at bottom of the screen

xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#000000"
           ></LinearLayout>

       <WebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>



        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is before clicking the tabs in the screen
[image]

After clicking the tabs white space is adding at bottom,and also scroll moves to bottom white space while clicking some of the tabs.

my java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scroll_example);

        mwebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
          mwebview.loadUrl("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxent-Executive/664900.html?creport=true&frompage=mobileapi");

          WebSettings webSettings = mwebview.getSettings();
          webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
          mwebview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

          mwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

White Space is added at bottom and it is adjusting itself when clicking last tab(i.e Terms and conditions).[image]

I really didnt understand whether the modification has to be done in Php side like Html data side or from our java side.

can anyone please suggest for solution.

Comment: Why do you want a ScrollView with the property `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: if I keep fill_parent also same issue

Comment: Webview inside a ScrollView is a structural challenge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255427/white-spaces-using-android-webview-inside-scrollview-with-a-jquery-mobile-web?rq=1

Comment: I too wonder why put a WebView in a ScrollView at all?

Comment: yes all, I have other views which has to scroll with the webview,this is my requirement.I know there is issue with Webview inside scrollview,but i need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think of something like this? 
Try using the `scrollview` as the root view, good luck!

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                ></LinearLayout>

            <WebView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/webview"/>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.